# Some Nine-patch not rendered when built from Windows 7

Tags: android

When I build a certain project on my Windows 7, some of the 9-patch are not considered as 9-patch at all: it extends the black area as if it was a standard image. (tested on a 2.2, 4.1 devices, a simulator and genymotion)

The part I do not understand is:

1. I built it on a MacOS and it works perfectly with the same sources
2. I built on a freshly configured Windows 7 on another PC and same problem
3. Most other 9-patch works from windows. I check each pixel's color on the border and png attributes: they are the same than the 9-patch that works. I modifyed them, same problem.
4. I updated the Android SDK, so it is now at least the third version that still have the issue.

Comment: are the file extensions `.9.png`? are the borders 100% black or transparent? are the borders 1 pixel wide?

Comment: Also this tool works great, as an alternative for the built in tool: http://digitalsquid.co.uk/patchworker/

Comment: Thanks, Yes for the .9 and yes for 100% transparency and the 1px wide.